# How to receive isometric indexes of cells from coordinate of mouse?

Tags: algorithm, math, isometric

I draw isometric map with tile **64x32**:

```
const Offset = 160;
int X, Y;

for (int a=0; a < 6; a++)
 for (int b=0; b < 6; b++) {
X = a * 32 - b * 32 + Offset;
Y = a * 16 + b * 16;
DrawTile(X, Y, tile);
 }
```

*Image, illustrating this code:* https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rc4kD.png

Dear professionals, please, help with a formula of transformation of mouse coordinates in isometric indexes of a cell. Example: (105; 100) -> [1; 4].

Thanks.

**P.S.** *Please excuse my bad English. I'm just learning...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two basis vectors p=(32,16) and q=(-32,16). Any vector r is linear combination of p and q:

```
r = a * p + b * q
components:
rx = a * 32 - b * 32 = (a - b) * 32
ry = a * 16 + b * 16 = (a + b) * 16
so your indexes are:
a = (2 * ry  + rx) div 64
b = (2 * ry  - rx) div 64
(div is integer division)
```

**Added:**
Note that I've used middle top point as coordinate zero and take into account your offset

Comment: note to include the offset just replace rx with (rx - offset)